# How to switch language in fish shell?

Tags: fish

I tried to switch languages in fish (eg. French as shell supports it) using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`, but nothing changed.
Exporting `LANG` variable doing `set --global --export LANG fr_FR.UTF-8` and launching child fish instance had no effect too. `locale` output is:

```
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

What actions are required to change fish-shell language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exploring related questions I found the solution: [set the environment variable in `~/.config/fish/config.fish`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/582287/terminal-fish-prompt-blank/582332#comment1084262_582332). So the first line of that config file may be `set --global --export LANG fr_FR.UTF-8`.
But it is still not clear to me why this approach works in contrast to the tried...